# how to replace a static kernel function without modifying and precomiling linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

all,
I want to know how to replace a kernel static function in a module without modifying linux kernel.
I have known that Linux hook can replace some functions, but the
problem is that I want to replace a static function without modifying linux kernel.
Would you please help me ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Generally the way the Linux kernel is compiled, replacing / hooking a static function at runtime isn't possible (short of unloading / reloading the entire module if you're talking module code).

That is because the compile *inlines* `static` functions much of the time (unless you take the address of it somewhere), and therefore they won't even show up in the symbol table. There's no way after the compile to find out where in the generated binary the `static` code ended up - not unlikely, you'll find several inlined versions of it in all the call sites invoking the func.

So the basic question: Why does the function have to be `static` ? What exactly is it you're attempting to do that mandates the use of `static` ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. We are doing a project that the customers don't allow to recomplie linux kernel. We have to replace the kernel function which is (static unsigned long get_next_ra_size(struct file_ra_state *ra, unsigned long max)) with a function writen by ourselves through insmod a module.

Comment: The customer is allowing you to insert kernel modules _and_ applying runtime patched hooks to the kernel they run but is not accepting an actual recompile ? That's technically unwise ... but anyway, in this situation get their kernel binaries (the vmlinux they use), disassemble it and find out whether`get_next_ra_size` is present (noninlined) and whether all calls in the sources are reflected by actual noninlined calls in the binary. If that is the case, then it is safe to runtime hook via kprobes / `int3` (x86/x64) - on this specific kernel.

Comment: Hello @ruby, I have a same situation as you, can you tell me your way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If it's actually compiled as a module (not built-in), then just recompile the code, `rmmod` the module, and `insmod` the new `.ko` file. Easy as... some kind of cliche pastry.

Comment: Though note that removing kernel modules can be _very_ tricky to get right -- it'd be easy to overlook one or another processor running code in the module that's being removed without clever machinations to ensure the module isn't currently being used.

Comment: Very true. `lsmod` is your friend, it can tell you which modules are currently using a particular module.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you may use some of this techniques:

- kprobes/jprobes, that allows you to hook a function with `int3`
- modifying the function's code (for ex., prologue) to jump to your handler and get back, later

If you don't wish to modify the kernel's code at all, you might set up the debugging registers and watch for an access exceptions (in your exception handler, of course). Besides that, you can try to find and invalidate some of the kernel's internal variables so the access to them from the kernel causes the invalid pointer dereference exception. In that case you can handle such an exception and do a back-trace to achive target function.

Comment: Thank you very much for you reply. Kprobes/jprobes is used to insert functions not replacing functions.About debugging registers, is linux kernel stable when you use it? Would you please tell me some details about debugging registers?

Comment: Well, when you are registering a kprobe, you'll get an ability to control the execution flow when the `int3` within a target function comes. So, in your handler you'll get a `pt_regs` pointer which can tell you all about the place where an exception occurs. You can simply look at the stack via the ebp(esp) register and get function's return address. After that, you can modify `eip` to point to the new code location, and after the exception finished eip will point to new address. As for debugging registers, they can be used to set so-called hardware breakpoints opposite to software ones (int3).